# How to find prime numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My goal here is to find the prime numbers:

```js
let arr = [2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15];
let ret = [];

arr.filter((z, ind) => {
  if (ind > 0) {
    ret.every(x => {
      !Number.isInteger(z / x) ? ret.push(z) : false;
    });
  } else {
    ret.push(z);
  }
});

console.log(ret);  // should be: [2,3,11]
```

It works for even numbers, but it doesn't work for the odd.

Comment: You aren't returning anything inside either block in the `filter`, what are you trying to use the `filter` for?

Comment: So it only works for 2.

Comment: @CertainPerformance he seems to use filter to traverse the array. I think it would be better to use forEach instead.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to just traverse the code, up until this problem I didn't realize there would such a difference btw filter and others. the inner most every was a filter in the beginning, and boy did that take me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your code:

```js
let arr = [2,3,4,6,9,10,11,15]
let ret = [];

arr.filter((z, ind) => {
   if(ind > 0){
     if(ret.every( x => !Number.isInteger(z/x)) ){
       ret.push(z)
     }
   } else { ret.push(z) }
 })

 console.log(ret)
```

Comment: You should replace `filter` with `forEach` as it is solely used for traversing the array.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Yup I agree. Although there are few other things as well that can be corrected here if the intention is to find the prime number from the list, However, I just wanted to make minimum changes in the OP's code and make it work.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi what other changes would you make? i.e. how can this be cleaner code

Comment: For e.g when you are checking if(ind >0) ... else ret.push(), you’re assuming at the 0th index there’s going to be 2. So why not put this in ‘ret’ from the beginning itself? Similarly for 3. Apart from that as suggested above, you should use map or forEach.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.filter()` method returns an array, so no need to generate the array by pushing the elements to an external array.

The prime check is easier with a `for` loop. Check that the number doesn't produce an integer if divided by all the numbers between 2 and half its size (rounded down). We need to check all half way, because every number that is greater than half the number we are checking, would produce a result that is less than 2, and 2 is the smallest integer divisor of a number.

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15];

const isPrime = num => {  
  if(num < 4) return true; // 1, 2, 3 are prime numbers

  const div = Math.floor(num / 2); // the max number to use as divider
  
  for(let i = 2; i <= div; i++) {
    if(Number.isInteger(num / i)) return false; // if the result is an integer, it's not a prime number
  }
  
  return true; // it's a prime number
};

const result = arr.filter(isPrime);

console.log(result);  // should be: [2,3,11]
```